# AngularJS Code Is Not working in Confluence

Tags: angularjs, confluence

I am utilizing HTML macro and trying to write AngularJS code in Confluence (ver. 5.8.17).

In the Confluence Editor, In the preview mode (when you press Preview), the code is working perfectly; however, if I save it and exit the Editor, it doesn't work as it is expected: apparently the binding is not working: what I enter in the textbox field does not show up in front of Hello in the line after it; instead I see, " Hello {{name}} ". Can you please help?

-PS: The code has been taken from below source: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">
</p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you see brackets that usually means console error.

Comment: From the same source (W3Schools), (I only shorten the quoted text though).

I think the issue is with the binding. the code below is not working too:


<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input ng-model="firstname">
    <h1>{{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "John";
    $scope.lastname = "Doe";    
});
</script>
<p>Change ...</p>
</body>
</html>